# Confidence Interval question about house holds

Tags: probability, confidence-interval

I was wondering if my calculation is right for this question

> A recent survey of 800 Irish households found that 74% of households
>   have a fixed line telephone. Infer a 95% confidence interval for the
>   percentage of the total population of Irish households that have a
>   fixed line telephone.

N = 800

P = .74

Q = 1  - .74 = .26

√(.74*.26/800) = 0.015

95% Z_Score = 1.96

74+%/- 1.96 * 0.015 = 0.03

> 74%+/-3%

Comment: Hello and welcome to math.stackexchange. The approach is correct, but where does this come from: √(.62*.32/350) = 0.015 .

Comment: Hi thanks, It was a typo I have edited it now,:),  so is the answer correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks good to me, including the numerical values. No need to report more digits.

Comment: Thanks  Hans Engler :)